# Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated Oracle

Tags: oracle, merge, sql-update

I am trying to update a column in a table using the value from another table. I am using table b to get my id's and joining to table a, this then has a dc_id and i am updating table c using that dc_id and the population_info_id.

But when using merge i get the error "Columns referenced in the ON Clause cannot be updated", but i need to use the population_info_id to identify the correct record. How can i get around this?

```
MERGE INTO table_c dc
USING (
          SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(A,12) PARALLEL(b,12) */
              a.dc_id,
              b.loaded_pii   AS loaded_pii,
              b.true_pii + 1 AS new_population_info_id
          FROM
              table_a           a
              INNER JOIN table_b   b 
              ON a.column_id= b.column_id
            
      )
src 
ON ( dc.dc_id = src.dc_id
        and dc.population_info_id = src.loaded_pii
        )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET dc.population_info_id = src.new_population_info_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some good options in [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900912/ora-38104-columns-referenced-in-the-on-clause-cannot-be-updated). One of them is that you can move that condition out of the `on` clause into a `where` clause:

```
MERGE INTO table_c dc
USING (
          SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(A,12) PARALLEL(b,12) */
              a.dc_id,
              b.loaded_pii   AS loaded_pii,
              b.true_pii + 1 AS new_population_info_id
          FROM
              table_a           a
              INNER JOIN table_b   b 
              ON a.column_id= b.column_id
            
      )
src 
ON ( dc.dc_id = src.dc_id ) -- from here
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET dc.population_info_id = src.new_population_info_id
WHERE dc.population_info_id = src.loaded_pii; -- to here
```

This could have some performance impacts. If that's not acceptable, consider trying one of the "renaming tricks" from those answers.

In your case, you can also do this with a plain update statement, but it's not exactly graceful since you need to duplicate the `src` subquery.

```
update table_c dc
set dc.population_info_id = (select b.true_pii + 1 as new_population_info_id
    from table_a           a
      INNER JOIN table_b   b 
      ON a.column_id= b.column_id
    where dc.dc_id = a.dc_id
      and dc.population_info_id = b.loaded_pii
    )
where exists (select 1 from table_a a
      INNER JOIN table_b   b 
      ON a.column_id= b.column_id
    where dc.dc_id = a.dc_id
      and dc.population_info_id = b.loaded_pii)
```

Comment: The first option could result in an `unable to get a stable set of rows` error. A row in the `USING` clause can't be permited to match more than one target row as defined by the `ON` clause, so the `ON` clause has to define uniqueness. If OP's inclusion of `population_info_id` is not due to it being part of the key then that should be fine (it shouldn't have been included in the `ON` clause in the first place). But if it's part of the key it will have to stay.

Answer (score 1):

Pre-join to your target within the `USING` clause and get the `ROWID` of the target rows to be updated (aliased to a non-keyword), and use that in your `ON` clause:

```
MERGE INTO table_c dc
USING (
          SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(12) */
              dc.rowid row_id
              b.true_pii + 1 AS new_population_info_id
          FROM
              table_a           a
              INNER JOIN table_b   b ON a.column_id= b.column_id
              INNER JOIN table_c dc ON dc.dc_id = a.dc_id
                                   AND dc.population_info_id = b.loaded_pii
            
      )
src 
ON ( dc.ROWID = src.row_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET dc.population_info_id = src.new_population_info_id;
```